# SQLPLUS output to shell script not returning value

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to return a sqlplus output to a shell script.  This may sound simple enough but I've searched online for some time and cannot get my script to work.

Here is my pl/sql script:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE 
X_RETURN_MSG VARCHAR2(32767);
X_RETURN_CODE NUMBER;

BEGIN 
X_RETURN_MSG := NULL;
X_RETURN_CODE := 5;

COMMIT;
END;

EXIT X_RETURN_CODE;
```

Here is my shell script:

```
sqlplus -s user/pwd <<EOF
@../sql/tester.sql
EOF
RETVAL=$?
echo $RETVAL
```

$RETVAL always returns 0 even when I have X_RETURN_CODE := 5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`X_RETURN_CODE` has no meaning outside of the scope of the PL/SQL block where it is declared.  You need to use a SQLPlus bind variable.

```
SQL> VARIABLE return_code NUMBER
SQL> BEGIN
  2    :return_code := 5;
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> EXIT :return_code
Disconnected from Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
> echo $?
5
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments and suggestions.  As always, this forum is one of the best.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is END marks the end of the block and X_RETURN_CODE goes out of scope so it defaults to 0. Or maybe you should look into using the RETURN statement instead of EXIT.

Comment: I think you're correct.  How would I get my return code in scope to exit with it's value?

Comment: Make it a function or procedure instead of an anonymous block.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sqlplus -s <<!
> / as sysdba
> @tester
> !

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

$ echo $?
5

$ cat tester.sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

var X_RETURN_CODE number

DECLARE
X_RETURN_MSG VARCHAR2(32767);

BEGIN
X_RETURN_MSG := NULL;
:X_RETURN_CODE := 5;

COMMIT;
END;
/

EXIT :X_RETURN_CODE;
```